# Is Graeme Souness the one who played and managed in 5 countries, winning European Cup as a player and Scottish Premier DIvision as a manager?

Tags: football, trivia

I ran into the following quiz question the other day, but I wasn't sure about the answer:

> Name the footballer who has played in 5 countries, winning the European cup, and has also managed in 5 countries, only winning a league title in Scotland.

The name that came to mind was Graeme Souness, but I'm not sure if this is correct.  Does he fit this description?  Is there anyone else who would fit it better?

Comment: Well, if you look at Wikipedia article about [Graeme Souness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeme_Souness), you will find there: 1) teams where he played; 2) teams where he worked as a coach/manager; 3) [titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeme_Souness#Honours) he won as a player/as a manager.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [Graeme Souness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeme_Souness)'s Wikipedia profile, he:

- Played in 5 countries:

  - England (Tottenham Hotspur, Middlesbrough, Liverpool)
  - Canada (Montreal Olympique)
  - Australia (West Adelaide)
  - Italy (Sampdoria)
  - Scotland (Rangers)
- Won 3 European Cups with Liverpool (1977–78, 1980–81, 1983–84) as a player
- Managed in 5 countries:

  - Scotland (Rangers)
  - England (Liverpool, Southampton, Blackburn Rovers, Newcastle United)
  - Turkey (Galatasaray)
  - Italy (Torino)
  - Portugal (Benfica)
- As a manager, only won a league title in Scotland; 3 times (1986–87, 1988–89, 1989–90)

So Graeme Souness is indeed the answer to your quiz.